# Servlet instance life time

Tags: java, servlets

My understanding of servlet instance is, there is only one instance of the servlet which is reused for multiple requests from multiple clients.

My question is, **where** the servlet container **store these instance** and how long **the life time of the instance**.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3):

*Where* --> RAM/Heap (It's an instance).

*How long?* --> Till servlet `destroy()` called (OR) JVM killed. You may refer [Servlet life cycle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

In memory and in accordance with the [Servlet Life Cycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html). The linked Tutorial says (in part)

> ## Servlet Life Cycle
>
> The life cycle of a servlet is controlled by the container in which the servlet has been deployed. When a request is mapped to a servlet, the container performs the following steps.
>
> 1. If an instance of the servlet does not exist, the web container
>
>    a. Loads the servlet class.
>
>    b. Creates an instance of the servlet class.
>
>    c. Initializes the servlet instance by calling the `init` method. Initialization is covered in [Initializing a Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html).
> 2. Invokes the `service` method, passing request and response objects. Service methods are discussed in [Writing Service Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafv.html).
>
> If the container needs to remove the servlet, it finalizes the servlet by calling the servlet’s `destroy` method. Finalization is discussed in [Finalizing a Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnags.html).

Comment: So i have added a ServletClass to a ServletContextHandler `context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(myServlet), "/myservice"); `. When i acces the corresponding webservice and modify some clas variables does that mean the next user who acceses the same webservice gets the variables i modified because it's the same instance?